# complex submanifolds in complex euclidean space

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Assume all manifolds are **without boundaries.** In Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, there are many submanifolds (Whitney Embedding Theorem).

In complex Euclidean space **$\mathbb{C}^n$**,  are there any typical examples of  complex submanifolds ?

My attempt: I only find the example:

(1). for any $m\leq n$, $\mathbb{C}^m$ is a complex submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^n$. And an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^m$ is a complex submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

(2). I find that any compact manifolds cannot be embedded as complex submanifolds of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Are there any other nontrivial **examples of complex submanifolds in $\mathbb{C}^n$?**

Answer (score 6):

You can take any projective manifold and take an open part of it that intersects with an affine chart $\{ (x_0 : \ldots : x_n) \mid x_n \neq 0 \}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb C^n$.

Complex manifolds that are closed submanifolds of $\mathbb C^n$ are known as Stein manifolds. Being Stein is the same as being acyclic, i.e. having all higher coherent sheaf cohomologies $H^i(M, \mathcal F)$ vanish, which makes Stein manifolds similar to affine manifolds in the algebraic world.

Comment: Dear Prof. Ivan, there are no closed (i.e. compact, without boundary) complex submanifolds of $\mathbb{C}^n$, by the maximum principle.

Comment: Dear Prof. Ivan, "Complex manifolds that are closed submanifolds of Cn are known as Stein manifolds." Do you mean that the manifold is closed as a topological space?

Comment: @haohaizi: maximum modulus principle only rules out complex *compact* submanifolds of $\mathbb C^n$. Yes, I used "closed" in the topological sense

Answer (score 3):

Consider a holomorphic map  $f=(f_1,\dots,f_p):\mathbb C^n\to \mathbb C^p$ and its zero locus $X=\{x\in \mathbb C^n\vert f(x)=0\}$.
 If the jacobian matrix $(\frac {\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(x))$  has rank $p$ at every $x\in X$, then $X\subset \mathbb C^n$ is a complex submanifold.
 The simplest example is a hypersurface i.e. the zero locus of a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb C^n\to \mathbb C $  whose gradient does not vanish on $X=f^{-1}(0)$.
 These hypersurfaces are exactly the closed submanifolds of dimension $n-1$ of $\mathbb C^n$.

**An explicit example**
Take  $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=x_1^k+\cdots+x^k_n-1\:(k\in \mathbb N^*)$ and obtain the Fermat hypersurface $x_1^k+\cdots+x^k_n=1$, a submanifold of dimension $n-1$ of $\mathbb C^n$.